# Adding a function to an element via javascript

Tags: javascript, function

So I have a loop that initializes elements and attributes from an array, and I've managed to add everything I need except one thing, a function.   The loop in question is below:

```
for (const character of result) {
    let image = document.createElement("img");
    image.src = character.src;
    image.setAttribute('data-jval', character.jval);
    image.setAttribute('id', character.id);
    image.setAttribute('class', character.class)
    image.setAttribute('draggable', 'true')
    // the below function isn't being added to the divs
    image.addEventListener('ondragstart', function(event){
        let data = event.target.dataset.jval;
        event.dataTransfer.setData("text", data);
    })
    let wrapper = document.createElement('div');
    wrapper.appendChild(image);
    section.appendChild(wrapper);
  }
```

and the function I'm trying to add to my elements is:

```
  function drag(event) {
    let data = event.target.dataset.jval;
    event.dataTransfer.setData("text", data);
  }
```

Before trying to create the elements in JavaScript I had them in HTML, and they looked like this:

```
<img data-jval="a" id="jval-a" src="./images/あ.png" class="j-char-img" draggable="true"  ondragstart="drag(event)"/>
```

but when I recreate it with my loop it looks like this, missing the ondragstart="drag(event"

```
<img src="/images/あ.png" data-jval="i" id="jval-i" class="j-char-img" draggable="true">
```

If the rest of my code would be useful I can post that as well.

Comment: If you dynamically attach the "ondragstart" event in your javascript code, you cannot seee it from the html attributes, but it should works. Please check whether it run into the function by adding a breakpoint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just "dragstart" instead of "ondragstart" event:

```
for (const character of result) {
    let image = document.createElement("img");
    image.src = character.src;
    image.setAttribute('data-jval', character.jval);
    image.setAttribute('id', character.id);
    image.setAttribute('class', character.class)
    image.setAttribute('draggable', 'true')

    // the below function isn't being added to the divs
    image.addEventListener('dragstart', drag);

    let wrapper = document.createElement('div');
    wrapper.appendChild(image);
    section.appendChild(wrapper);
  }

  function drag(event) {
    let data = event.target.dataset.jval;
    event.dataTransfer.setData("text", data);
  }
```

So basically you add the prefix `on` before the event when you write inline event handlers, just like before when you put your event handler inside your `img` tag. Same thing for any other events:

```
click => onclick
submit => onsubmit
keydown => onkeydown
```

Comment: Hey this totally did it!  If I can ask a follow up question, while developing this webpage I feel like I'm not totally understanding how everything works all the time since the code keeps getting longer and I can't always recall how I implemented the script... is this normal?  Also, would just re-doing it from scratch be a useful exercise to get a better grasp?

Comment: I'm assuming that you are new to coding. It's common to forget how to implement the script at the beginning. If you can't recall it, take a step back, try to solve it as a new problem, even watching some tutorials might help. However, make sure that you understand everything you write. That's the key. Don't imitate, understand.

Comment: If you find my answer clearing up your question, please don't forget to upvote it. Happy coding! =))

Answer (score 0):

```js
#try to add Semicolon;
    image.setAttribute('class', character.class);
    image.setAttribute('draggable', 'true');
    // the below function isn't being added to the divs
    image.addEventListener('ondragstart', function(event){
        let data = event.target.dataset.jval;
        event.dataTransfer.setData("text", data);
    });
```